# Neural Network and predicting the effects of different independent variables on dependent variable

Tags: regression

I am new to this. For a project, I am trying to find a relation between 5 independent variables on one dependent variable. I am  specifically looking to find intricate relation between how user violation (of different natures) affect the traffic flow. I want to use neural network to find the relationships but I fear the model might overfit. What might be the solution to this ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.